# how to define the probability distribution

Tags: probability, distribution

I have small question and I will be very happy if you can give me a solution or any idea for solution of probability distribution of the following idea: 
I have a random variable x which follows exponntial  distribution with parameter lambda1,I have one more variable y which follows exponential  distribution with parameter lambda2. z is a discrete value, how can I define the probability distribution of  k in the following formula ?

k=z-x-y

Thank you so much

Comment: That's a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) problem. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Sum_of_two_i.i.d._exponential_random_variables) for an example that's very close to your problem. If my memory serves me correctly, it's much easier to do this type of calculation with moment generating functions than doing the integrals directly.

Comment: @apophis Since z is a discrete variable and x and y are continuous, that seems like it would make this problem a little unconventional ... Perhaps it is possible to make progress by representing the discrete distribution as a weighted sum of impulse (i.e. delta) functions (so that it becomes a function of a continuous variable). I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @Robert Dodier Agreed, that sounds really difficult. My understanding was that though z might be variable, it is not a *random* variable.

Comment: @apophis Sure it is a random variable - anything is. PDF(t) = (t-z)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lets start with rewriting formula a bit:

```
k = z-x-y = -(x-y) + z = - (x + y + -z)
```

That parts in the parentheses looks manageable. Let's start with `x+y`. For random variable `x` and `y` if one wants to find out their sum, answer is PDFs convolution.

```
q = x+y

PDF(q) = S PDFx(q-t) PDFy(t) dt
```

where `S` denotes integration. For `x` and `y` being exponential, the convolution integral is known and equal to expression [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Sum_of_two_i.i.d._exponential_random_variables) when lambdas are different, or to Gamma(2,lambda) when lambdas are equal, Gamma being [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

If `z` is some constant discrete value, then we could express it as continuous RV with PDF

```
PDF(t) = (t+z)
```

where  is [Delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), and we take into account that peak would be at `-z` as expected. It is normalized, so integral over `t` is eqaul to 1. It could be easily extended to discrete RV, as sum of -functions at those values, multiplied by probabilities such that sum of them is equal to 1.

Again, we have sum of two RV, with known PDFs, and solution is convolution, which is easy to compute due to property of -function. So final PDF of `x + y + -z` would be

```
PDF(q+z) dq
```

where PDF is taken from sum expression from Exponential distribution wiki, of Gamma distribution from Gamma wiki.

You just have to negate, and that's it

Comment: K=Z-(X+Y)

 I applied convolution for PDF of two exponential random variables (X and Y). Which is like $f_{U}(u)=\lambda^2 u e^{-\lambda.u}$. What am going to do now for delta function I am struggling here to find the pdf of k? z- \lambda^2 u e^{-\lambda.u}$. ? I will be very appreciate if anyone can help me

Comment: @Angelıque I will write small doc over weekend and send it to you, if it's ok. Are you interested?

Comment: @Angelıque try to get what I wrote at this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3BW2IWIJdqEJ02FDxLmGyHt09iFiDbL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Angelıque did you receive the write-up?